# possible combinations of a dataset and average of corresponding column using r

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations, average

I have a dataframe named "Hits" with some values given below

```
     Hits   RA
1  A415Z   1.01
2  A415J   0.91
3  B416X   0.95
4  B416Z   0.97
5  B416J   1.03
6  B416M   1.16
7  B416P  11.75
8  B416W   0.98
9  D420R   0.98
10 D420H   0.94
11 D420Z   1.01
12 D420J   1.01
13 D420F    0.9
14 D420L      1
15 C462H   0.93
16 C462P   0.83
17 C462W   0.73
```

Now, I would like to make possible combinations of this dataset in notations of 2 for that i made use of this function
combn from the package "combinat" and there is the output below. The below given output represents only the head 
of the dataframe.

```
       value            
1   A415Z  A415J     
2   A415Z  B416X    
3   A415Z  B416Z     
4   A415Z  B416J    
5   A415Z  B416M
```

I would like to make another column where for each hit in each row their corresponding RA values are obtained and 
from the original dataframe and the average of RA to be obtained  such that the output looks like this one dataframe 
given below.

```
        value        RA
1   A415Z  A415J    0.96
2   A415Z  B416X    0.98
3   A415Z  B416Z    0.99  
4   A415Z  B416J    1.02
5   A415Z  B416M    1.08
```

Comment: *"for that i made use of this function combn from the package "combinat" and there is the output below"* -- include this code in your question.

Comment: @AmrithaAmarnath DId you `paste`d the two row output from `combn` to create the second dataset?

Comment: yes, i did use paste for putting them together. I made a small function. 
combinations<-function(strings){
  combo1<-combn(strings,2)
  combo2<-paste(combo1[1,],combo1[2,])
  return(combo2)
}
combos<-combinations(Hits$Hits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse` to do this.  The 'value' column from the second dataset (based on the `combinat` output) is split into two columns, and `left_join` with the first dataset to get the 'RA' values, get the `mean` and `select` the columns of interest

```
library(tidyverse)
separate(df2, value, into = c('value1', 'value2'), remove = FALSE) %>%
        left_join(., df1, by = c(value1 = 'Hits')) %>%
        left_join(., df1, by = c(value2= 'Hits')) %>% 
        mutate(RA= round((RA.x+RA.y)/2, 2)) %>%
        select(-RA.x, -RA.y, -value1, -value2)
#        value   RA
#1 A415Z  A415J 0.96
#2 A415Z  B416X 0.98
#3 A415Z  B416Z 0.99
#4 A415Z  B416J 1.02
#5 A415Z  B416M 1.08
```

---

This can be also done with `base R`

```
RA1 <-  utils::combn(df1[,1], 2, FUN = function(x) mean(df1[,2][match(x, df1[,1])]))
d1 <- as.data.frame(t(utils::combn(df1[,1], 2)))
d1$RA <- round(RA1, 2)
head(d1)
#     V1    V2   RA
#1 A415Z A415J 0.96
#2 A415Z B416X 0.98
#3 A415Z B416Z 0.99
#4 A415Z B416J 1.02
#5 A415Z B416M 1.08
#6 A415Z B416P 6.38
```

Comment: one can use `mutate(h2 = Hits) %>%
  expand(Hits, h2)` instead of the `combinat` as well

Comment: Thankyou so much for the answer @ akrun. It did help me out a lot

Comment: @akrun yes. would require a filter `filter(Hits != h2)` as well.

Comment: When I make use of the above mentioned code from the package "tidyverse". It does retrieve the RA values 
but gives NAs  for RA.x , RA.y and few warnings. Can someone help by pointing out why this happens.
Thankyou in advance.

Comment: @AmrithaAmarnath  Based on your example, it is working fine for me.

Comment: These are the warnings i get 
Warning messages:
1: Too many values at 5 locations: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
2: In left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y) :
  joining factor and character vector, coercing into character vector
3: In left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y) :
  joining factor and character vector, coercing into character vector

Comment: @AmrithaAmarnath  I can only work on the example you showed.